# Is there any official GWT(2.4) Validation Framework?

Tags: gwt

I am a newbie in GWT. Currently using GWT 2.4 for our development project. Now facing a problem with Client side validation due to lack of documentation on Validation.

Now I want to know 'Is there any Google official validation framework for GWT 2.4?' [Not code project]. If not, then what are the alternatives + good documentation/tutorial?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I have never heard of native validation support. Try [gwt-validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/), which is a bean validation framework. They have a demo project and description. It's not official, of course, but can be helpful. [GXT library](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/) also provides validation tools, although it is a commercial one.

Hopefully they will eventually decide to merge gwt-validation project into GWT, since it's a really important issue.

Comment: Just tried with GWT Sample (Validation)/Bean validation. But documentation is too poor,hard to understand!

Answer (score 1):

GWT 2.4 supports [Java Bean Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) on the client side (with [limitations](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation#What_is_not_supported)). Unfortunately there's only [little documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation), but you can see a [introduction to it here](http://gglwebtoolkit.blogspot.de/2011/12/client-side-bean-validation-with-gwt.html).

As far as I remember, GWT bean validation can be used with the [Editor Framework](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors).

For extended bean validation support, you can use [gwt-validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/).

Edit: There will possibly be [better support of Bean Validation (JSR 303) in GWT 2.5](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110412141990454266397/posts/GQ3QVCgTiLo)

Comment: Thanks bro! Great link indeed.

Comment: there is no need for gwt-validation, you can everything with the standard bean validation. Dont mix them, or suffer with pride :)

Comment: @koma GWT 2.4 has some limitations of the bean validation support. As far as I know, gwt-validation supports some of the missing stuff. Ray Cromwell recently announced better support of bean validation in GWT (possibly 2.5): https://plus.google.com/u/0/110412141990454266397/posts/GQ3QVCgTiLo

Comment: IMO, it is the same one as for 2.4 but more complete. and the package structure changed slightly. Anyway, no additional modules like gwt-validation required.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind server side validation, you can use [RequestFactory](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideRequestFactory#validation).

Answer (score 0):

I agree w/ you that there needs to be better and simpler native support for client side validation. In the meantime you might have a gander here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/15989932.